# PHP Loop on table

Tags: php, loops

I have done upload files to server and mysql database, im displaying images from database on my table when someone uploads image I want to have maximum 3 columns and the 4th image I want to be displayed in 1st column and 2nd row etc. so I need to write loop I think, but don't know how to do this.

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());   

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    $link = $row['link'];
    $catg = $row['kategoria'];
    $comm = $row['komentarz'];

    switch($catg){ 
        case "standing": 
            echo "<td>";?> <img src="img/<?php echo $catg; ?>/<?php echo $link; ?>" width="150" height="150"> <?php echo "</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: `If counter equals 3 - start new row`

Comment: but really I cant do loop for this

Comment: Really can't do what - `$i++`? `$i/3`?

Answer (score 0):

Use mod division:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());   

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

$c=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    $c++;
    $link = $row['link'];
    $catg = $row['kategoria'];
    $comm = $row['komentarz'];

    switch($catg){ 
        case "standing": 
            echo "<td>";?> <img src="img/<?php echo $catg; ?>/<?php echo $link; ?>" width="150" height="150"> <?php echo "</td>";
    }

    if ($c % 3 == 0) echo "</tr><tr>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```